# Example of REST controller specs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, rspec, tdd

I'm trying to learn to do TDD. I'm having difficulty though, finding out what exactly it is I should be testing for each action in a RESTful controller. What I really would like is a sample of the most basic spec for a RESTful controller, which would help me figure out what I should be testing. If it matters, I'm using RSPec with Capybara. I'm not looking for something I can crib, just a sample I can examine so I know whether I'm going in the right direction.

Comment: http://matthewlehner.net/rails-api-testing-guidelines/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an answer here before that got deleted, and the user suggested the Rails tutorial. It was pretty good for learning what to test, and can be found at http://www.railstutorial.org/book with chapters three and nine being most useful for someone just looking at it for TDD purposes.

Since then I've also found an older article that's really handy combined with the tutorial (and a bit of digging), simply because it's now highly out of date. This is found at the Everyday Rails blog,  at http://everydayrails.com/2012/03/12/testing-series-intro.html.

Ultimately it looks like there may not be a good, solid, easy tutorial on how and what to test for Rails 4 with RSpec 3. Perhaps something you pros could consider!